# How can I make my windows transparent by doing Alt+Mouse Scroll?

Tags: window, transparency

Pressing and holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> + scrolling with the mouse wheel used to give me a transparent window, is there any way I can get that or something similar in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Install these packages with the command

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

This will install the CompizConfig-Settings-Manager and necessary plugins required.

Open the CompizConfig-Settings-Manager by typing **ccsm** in the dash. In the CCSM's window, under the *Accessibility* section, enable the *Opacity, Brightness and Satuaration* by placing a tick mark on the corresponding checkbox.

[image: CCSM]

This should automatically enable the plugin, if it does not, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `compiz --replace` to restart compiz. A nicer way would be logout and login again.

Now you can increase or decrease the transparency of any window by holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and scrolling mouse wheel.

**Note:** If Unity seems crashed, don't be bothered. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to bring logout window, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to logout from your session. Then login again.

---

### For Non-Unity users

Users who are using Lubuntu or Xubuntu, they will miss this feature because those flavor doesn't use *Compiz* as the window manager. Lubuntu uses OpenBox and Xubuntu uses XFWM window manager. To be able to use this feature, compiz should be used as the window manager.

One way to achieve this is adding a `compiz --replace` command in startup of the session. (There are neat way of replacing default wm with compiz, but this will do the job)

After enabling compiz, you need to enable some basic plugin using CompizConfig-SettingsManager. These plugins are -

- Window Decoration (For decorating windows)
- Animations
- Maximumize (for maximize)
- Move Window (enable moving)
- Place Window (will place new window in suitable place)
- Resize Window (to be able to resize)
- Application Switcher (Alt-Tab functionality)
- Composite
- OpenGL

These are basics. But you can try others too. I would recommend enabling *Scale*, *Expo*, *Desktop Wall* too.

After enabling these and getting a stable compiz working in your LX/XFCE DE, proceed with the instruction above.

Comment: @Eccentric_Geek A little nice tutorial, on how to do it per app: http://cupugila.blogspot.de/2012/08/make-ubuntu-unity-window-look.html

Comment: @Anwar Shah, immediately after I press Alt+F2 and type compiz --replace(otherwise the opacity doesn't work) the x(close) ,minimize and resize from top-right of all the open windows disappear and I can't resize any more any windows even with pulling the margins with the mouse, and the alt key doesn't work any more in any windows.

Comment: @XPDIN which version of Ubuntu are you using? There should be a unity --reset command in newer versions of Ubuntu. I'm on 14.04

Comment: @Anwar Shah For the moment I am using Lubuntu 15.10, tell me please, what should I do? I am Linux beginner user.

Comment: Can you log out and login again. If not, use ctrl-alt-del key combo. If you still having problem, install compizconfig-settings-manager and in the advanced tab, select unity problem and click reset button.

Comment: @AnwarShah, still not working, I installed from the beginning sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra. I should uninstall and install it again, or tell me please, where I can find advanced tab without uninstalling?

Comment: @XPDIN sorry for late reply. You have to enable some plugins first to be able to use compiz in Xubuntu or Lubuntu etc. See the update of the answer

Comment: Working perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04 LTE. Thank you very much.